# Web form attaches pdf, but not valid?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, webforms, itext, email-attachments

Using Itext sharp pdf and have a form that takes input, then it takes that input, including the user's email address, makes the pdf, then sends an email with the pdf attached at the user inputted email address. That said, the attachment and pdf generation works, but when you download or try to open the pdf, it does not open or anything. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace pacfam
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void ShowPdf(string filename)
        {
            //Clears all content output from Buffer Stream
            Response.ClearContent();
            //Clears all headers from Buffer Stream
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            //Adds an HTTP header to the output stream
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);
            //Gets or Sets the HTTP MIME type of the output stream
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            //Writes the content of the specified file directory to an HTTP response output stream as a file block
            Response.WriteFile(filename);
            //sends all currently buffered output to the client
            Response.Flush();
            //Clears all content output from Buffer Stream
            Response.Clear();
        }

        protected void btnShow_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //create variable from input in textbox control
            var textInput = useIn.Text;

            //server folder path which is stored your PDF documents
            string path = Server.MapPath("PDF-Files");
            string filename = path + "/Doc1.pdf";

            //Create new PDF document 
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f);

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));

            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph(textInput));
            document.Close();

            ShowPdf(filename);

            //setups and builds email to send to user
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("xxxx.xxxxxxx.com", 587);
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            //grabs form data in memory for pdf to attach to email
            MemoryStream memNow = new MemoryStream();

            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx@xxxx.com", "password");
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("pacificfamily@blueskyprojects.com", TextBox2.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox6.Text);
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memNow, "Doc1.pdf"));
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }

    }
}
```

The link to the actual form as this is the code behind is here:

```
http://67.228.49.104:8080/surveymain
```

It does attach a PDF and I confirmed on the server that the PDF is created (shows a pdf with a while size), however, the file size for the PDF sent via email is shown (if downloaded) with a file size of 0. So not sure what is happening here or where my code could be wrong.

Any thoughts as to what is going on here?

Thanks much.

Comment: Doesn't `mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memNow, "Doc1.pdf"));` attach the contents of `memNow`? That variable in your case is a newly generated `MemoryStream`, i.e. empty.

Comment: Make that an answer, mkl ;-)

Comment: Well, I was not sure, the .Net APIs are a bit foreign to me... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mkl said, you are creating a brand new empty `MemoryStream` and adding it to the `Attachments` collection with the fake name `Doc1.pdf`. You can fix this in one of two ways.

## 1 - Use the actual file

Just use the actual file that you've generated and attach that:

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(filename));
```

## 2 - Bypass the disk completely

Unless you have a need to store the file to disk you can just write directly to a `MemoryStream` and then use that in your email. The code below is a more drastic change so I've taken the liberty of also switching over to the `using` pattern to handle object disposal.

```
//Hold everything in memory
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {

    //Create new PDF document 
    using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f)) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms)) {

            //Tell the PdfWriter not to close the stream when it is done
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            document.Close();
        }
    }

    //Reset the stream
    ms.Position = 0;

    //setups and builds email to send to user
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("xxxx.xxxxxxx.com", 587);
    smtp.EnableSsl = false;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;


    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("xyz@example.com", TextBox2.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox6.Text);

    //Add our stream and assign it an arbitrary file anem
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "Doc1.pdf"));
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! That was it. Funny how we sometimes over complicate it!